# use of inherited attributes and "struct" in a c++ subclass

Tags: c++

how do I use a superclass "Struct" in the subclass. I usually use attributes:

```
   using superclass<T>::Attribute;
```

But for a "Struct" with internal methods I do not know how you can do.
However the superclass "struct" is declared protected as its attributes.

In the Superclass:

```
protected:

  struct Node{

    Data Elements;
    struct Node* Nxt;

    methods......

  }
```

I tried with:

`using Superclass<T>::Node;`  and  `using Superclass<T>::struct Node;`

but he gives me this mistake:

```
error: dependent using declaration resolved to type without 'typename'
  using List<Data>::Node;
```

Comment: Have you tried `using Superclass<typename T>::Node` as the error message suggests?

Comment: even there gives me error @Ken Y-N                                                                      
 error: dependent using declaration resolved to type without 'typename'
  using List<typename Data>::Node;

Comment: Try: `using typename Superclass<typename T>::Node`.

Comment: thanks so much I solved the problem @Evg

Comment: Great. Please refer to the dupe for an explanation why you need `typename`.